# Apply a set of functions randomly on a python dictionary with random.shuffle()

Tags: python, function, dictionary

So I have a set of functions say `f1(dict) , f2(dict) , f3(dict)`
Each one checks a condition and if the condition is not met removes an element from the dict.

I want to apply these three functions on a dictionary  `a ={}`. But I want to apply them in random order (so that one condition is not predominant over the others in the final remaining elements of the dictionary)

What's best way to do this in python?

Comment: I'd try it myself first, make  a set of 3 numbers, then pick from it randomly. First you'll need a random number from 0 to 2, then you pop the picked number and make if.. elif..else blocks. Repeat for 0..1. Later use numpy random choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `random.shuffle()` function:

```
import random

functions = [f1, f2, f3]
random.shuffle(functions)
for function in functions:
    function(mydict)
```

Comment: Ah, didn't realize he wanted to apply all 3 in random order.

Comment: One more clarification, function=[] indicates a list of my methods is it?

Comment: Yes.  I first define a list of your functions, and then I shuffle the list with `random.shuffle()` so that they appear in a random order.  Then, I go through each function and call it with the dictionary as an argument.